# Try/catch in for-loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, if-statement, try-catch

I'm new to programming and trying to solve a problem. I've got an array I want to fill with input from a user but I want to make sure it's only integers between 1-25 and no string input. How do I do this?

The code I've gotten this far is this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < lottery.Length; i++)
{
    Console.Write(i + ": ");

    try
    {
        input = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        lottery[i] = input;
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Only integers!");
        i--;
    }
}
```

This codes makes sure the only input to the array is integers but how do I get the user to only write numbers between 1-25? I've tried diffrent if-statements and other loops 3 hours but can't solve it. Please help.

Comment: Wrong, do not control code using exceptions. Use TryParse instead and remove the exception

Comment: I would advise to look up what a `while` look is. Basically within a single iteration of the `for` loop you want to keep asking for number untill a correct integer value is provided.

Comment: `if(input>=1 && input<=25)`.........?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should not use exceptions to drive through your code. Exceptions are costly things in terms of performances and if there is a way to avoid them you should always use that way.
In your case you should use [int32.TryParse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.tryparse) instead of Parse. This TryParse doesn't raise an exception if the input is not a valid integer number but returns false or true while the parsed number (if it is an integer) is returned in the out parameter passed to the method.

This allows to write a lot simpler code with a while loop to continue input in case of errors.

```
        for (int i = 0; i < lottery.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.Write(i + ": ");

            // Start the loop with an invalid input
            int input = 0;
            while(input == 0)
            {
                if(int32.TryParse(Console.ReadLine(), out input);
                {
                    // Got a valid integer, add out acceptance logic here
                    if(input > 0 && input <= 25)
                        lottery[i] = input;
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Type a number between 1 and 25");

                        // Not a valid range. Force the loop to continue
                        input = 0;
                    }
                }
                else
                    Console.WriteLine("Write only integers between 1-25");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
int[] lottery = new int[5];
        for (int i = 0; i < lottery.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i + ": ");
            int input; 
            while(true)
            {
                string inp = Console.ReadLine();
                if(Int32.TryParse(inp, out input) == true)
                {
                    if (0 < input & input <= 25)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Only numbers 1-25");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Only Integers");
                }
                    
            }
               
            lottery[i] = input;

            
        }
```

Comment: please include descriptions in your answer - code-only is not that helpful.